# Getting 403 Forbidden error when requesting JSON output with apikey

Tags: python, json, http, request, urllib

I am trying to request information from a server with Python. The API key is correct however I still get the 403 error. It works with curl, but not with Python.

Here is the curl code that outputs JSON:

`curl -H "apiKey: xxx"  https://kretaglobalmobileapi.ekreta.hu/api/v1/Institute/3928`

And here is my code that outputs Forbidden error:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen 
import json
ker = Request('https://kretaglobalmobileapi.ekreta.hu/api/v1/Institute/3928')
ker.add_header('apiKey', 'xxxx')
content = json.loads(urlopen(ker))
print(content)
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urlopen usually returns a HTTPResponse object. So in order to read the contents use the read() function. Other wise your code looks fine.

```
req = Request('https://kretaglobalmobileapi.ekreta.hu/api/v1/Institute/3928')
req.add_header('apikey', 'xxx')
content = urlopen(req).read()

print(content).
```

You can also use another library for instance requests if the above method dosent work,

```
r = requests.get('<MY_URI>', headers={'apikey': 'xxx'})
```

Comment: `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
File "/home/lori/PycharmProjects/HOT/bot.py", line 5, in <module>
content = urlopen(ker).read()` Still not working. No problem  with the JSON output I think.

Comment: Can you try using different libraries, i often use **requests** library and it gets the job done most of the time.
`r = requests.get('<MY_URI>', headers={'apikey': 'xxx'})`

Comment: Worked with requests. I have no idea why it didn't work with urllib. Thanks for the help! Edit your answer so I can tick it.